# Substitute and colorize arguments in console.log()

Tags: javascript, node.js, chalk

There's a nice module for `Node.js` called `chalk` that allows to apply coloring and text formatting to `console.log()` function.

If I write something like this:

```
console.log("test string substitution with coloring: %s, %s", chalk.red("red"), chalk.magenta("magenta"));
```

it will use string substitution and outputs red and mageenta properly colored:

[image]

Now what I am trying to make is to make functions that accepts text with substitution literals as first parameter and variable amount of parameters later that should:

1. substitude corresponding substitution literals (just as regular `console.log()` does);
2. each passed parameter shall be colored with red using `chalk.red()`;

For example:

```
function log(text, ...args) {
   // magic here
}

log("This must be %s, and %s as well", "red", "this must be red");
```

This shall give this:

[image: example]

I have tried to use `console.log(text, chalk.red.apply(null, args))` but it doesn't seems to produce what I want.

Comment: no, that link is about colors in browser's console

Comment: it does try once

Comment: the same. Again I know how to add colors, What I do not know how to achieve what I asked.

Comment: Fix your question then.  It's a question about adding colours to text, but not what you're saying you actually want is to write a function similar to `string.format()`.  Remove all the irrelevant colour references if you want your question to be clear.

Comment: dude, come on,read again: Now what I am trying to make is to make functions that accepts text with substitution literals as first parameter and variable amount of parameters later that should:

substitude corresponding substitution literals (just as regular console.log() does);
each passed parameter shall be colored with red using chalk.red();

Comment: I've read it and advised you to fix it.  Good luck with your problem.

Comment: I gave an example with proper description of what I am trying to achieve in initial post, step by step.

Comment: I thought the question was clear @kaytrance.

Comment: Thank you @MarkMeyer! And @Archer please remove suggestion to close a topic then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to spread an array into the `console.log()`. For example, you can do it inline with `map()`:

```
let chalk = require('chalk')

console.log("test string substitution with coloring: %s and %s",  ...["red", "this must be red"].map(t => chalk.red(t)));
```

Of course, you could make it a function as well:

```
function log(text, ...args){
    console.log(text,  ...args.map(t => chalk.red(t)));    
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Works exactly as I asked!

Comment: If you wanted to omit the `chalk` dependency you can utilize the [ANSI/VT100 Control sequences](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) directly. In which case the `chalk.red(t)` part in both examples above can be replaced with `\`\x1b[31m${t}\x1b[0m\``